# HTML CSS/JS Bottom navbar Sliding Up

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I've done some research and it doesn't seem that I can find exactly what I'm looking for. My goal is to have a navigation bar on the bottom of my JS-app and when a user clicks a certain button, it would start an animation where the navbar travels from the bottom of the app to the top of the app. Here's some edits I made to illustrate what I mean:

[default position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIEAx.png)

[after user presses "profile" button, for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpriO.png)

Not sure what JS library would help me with this or if there is a code-sample. The key here is that I dont want it to shift on any button clicked, only certain ones. For example, if the user clicks on "Library" from my example above, I want it to stay on the bottom.

Might anyone know how I can accomplish this?

EDIT: so the reason im doing this is because this is an electron app that i want some content to be local, and some content to be remote. This is why when the users presses "Library" i would want the navbar to remain stationary. However if the user presses "Profile" it would shift to the top and the "content" window would act sort of like a web-browser in that it would load a page on a remote webserver. I hope that helps. And thanks for all the info!

EDIT 2: A little off-topic, but i get this weird padding that im not sure where is coming from:

[weird space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeyR7.png)

EDIT 3:

Heres the HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="renderer.js"></script>
 <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<body>
<script>
  function toggleNavLocation() {
    //alert('clciiikkkked');
    $('nav').toggleClass('top');
  }
</script>
<nav>
  <div id="logo_container"><img id="logo" 
 src="./assets/images/poscon_nav.jpg" width="100px" height="55px" /></div>
  <div id="navitems">
  <ul>
    <li id="dashboard">DASHBOARD</li>
    <li id="pilotclient">PILOT CLIENT</li>
    <li id="livemap">LIVE MAP</li>
    <li id="community">COMMUNITY</li>
    <li id="profile" onclick="toggleNavLocation()">PROFILE</li>
    <li id="training">TRAINING</li>
    <li id="support">SUPPORT</li>
    <li id="library">LIBRARY</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="right_content">
  <div id="user_pane">
    <span id="username"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="center_content">

</div>

<div id="left_content">

</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }

 nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:850;
  height:75px;
  background: rgb(27, 27, 80);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }

 nav.top {
  bottom:calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }

 #dashboard, #pilotclient, #livemap, #community, #profile, #training, 
 #support, #library, #search_img {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: rgb(81, 81, 81);
  padding-top: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height:75px;
  background:rgb(27, 27, 27);
  text-align:center;
 }

#dashboard:hover, #pilotclient:hover, #livemap:hover, #community:hover, 
#profile:hover, #training:hover, #support:hover, #library:hover {
  background: #252525;
}

#logo_container {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 2px;
}

#navitems {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 150px;
 height: 100px;
}

#right_content {
 width: 250px;
 height: 575px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 background-color: red;
}

#center_content {
 width: 500px;
 height: 575px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 250px;
 background-color: blue;
}

#left_content {
 width: 250px;
 height: 575px;
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: green;
}

#user_pane {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 background-color: green;
}

#username {
 width: 200px;
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 175px;
 left: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: The best way for people to assist you is to post the minimum code itself that you have tried. [mcve]

Comment: Use case described isn't clear at all.. why would you want to jump your navigation bar across screen on some buttons clicks. what are you trying to acheive ? and also what @imvain2 said,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some JS to add a class to your nav bar to do the animation, and you can add this class when clicking on a button with specific IDs.

Below is a snippet that demonstrates this:

```js
$('#profile').on('click', function(){
  toggleNavLocation();
});

function toggleNavLocation() {
$('nav').toggleClass('top');
}
```

```css
nav {
  width:100vw;
  height:50px;
  background:#000;
  bottom: 0;
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

nav.top {
  bottom:calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

li {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:25px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
text-align:center;
line-height:25px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="profile">Profile</li>
<li id="library">Library</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want it to animate, but just jump to top or bottom, then you can remove all of these lines:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
```

Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
$('#profile').on('click', function(){
  toggleNavLocation();
});

function toggleNavLocation() {
$('nav').toggleClass('top');
}
```

```css
nav {
  width:100vw;
  height:50px;
  background:#000;
  bottom: 0;
  color:#fff;
  position: absolute;
}

nav.top {
  bottom:calc(100% - 50px);
}

li {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:25px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
text-align:center;
line-height:25px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="profile">Profile</li>
<li id="library">Library</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

These examples us some JQuery, but if you want pure JS, you should be able to port it over to Vanilla with a bit of thought put into the code I have supplied.

Comment: This is verrrrry useful. ill give it a shot. much appreciated good sir.

Comment: No problem my friend!

Comment: width:100%; change to width:100vw;

Comment: add left:0; to nav CSS

Comment: so after some debug and finally getting around to doing the JS part, i notice that it doesnt quite work.i added an onclick event to the actual li item that executes the toggleNavLocation function and threw in an alert to ensure it was being called. It is and the alert went off, however the nav never actually shifts position. Updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty straight forward but we need to know which property did you use to position the navbar at the bottom?. Best solution would be to create two css Properties of different properties in flexbox behavior then just use JavaScript to change the nav id corresponding the properties when the profile is clicked.

Comment: yep, nothing complex..just want it to shift up to the top of the app. I haven't put any code in just yet as i wanted to start with a good idea for what code i would need.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the navbar to slide between 2 vertical positions with css as such:-

```
@keyframes animatebottom {
from {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0
}
to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1
}
}
```

Modify the "bottom" property to suit your page height and other requirements.