# Slide up window in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to add a button/tab on the bottom right corner of the page. That when clicked slides up a window. I've seen this somewhere but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi There. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck ? Post more code.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer shortly after. If you're looking for the same, this thread might help:
[HTML CSS/JS Bottom navbar Sliding Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284741/html-css-js-bottom-navbar-sliding-up)